# Graficar ecuación en py

Tags: python, matplotlib, gráficas

buenas tardes disculpen alguien puede ayudarme?
Soy nuevo en programación y debo hacer un ejercicio para mi trabajo. Necesito graficar en 3d una función:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde:
`Xo=5,Yo=5, A=1, σx=1, σy=1`. `x` y `y` van de 0 a 10 en intervalos de 0.1

¡Les agradecería mucho su ayuda! Hasta ahora llevo éste avance pero sólo me sale 2D:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
#ax = Axes3D(fig) 
X0=5
Y0=5
A=1
Ox=1
Oy=1
X=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
Y=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
op1=((X-X0)**2)
op2=(2*(Ox**2))
op3=((Y-Y0)**2)
op4=(2*(Oy**2))
op5=((op1/op2)+(op3/op4))
op6=(op5*-1)
f=np.exp(op6)
fxy=A*f
Z=(fxy)
ax= fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')


plt.plot(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento. Saludos.

Comment: 1) cambia `X=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
Y=np.arange(0,10,0.1)` a `x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=np.arange(0,10,0.1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)` 2) cambia `plt.plot(X, Y, Z)` a `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)`

Comment: muchas gracias¡

Comment: Ahora investigo el error que me sale en argumento "Z" porque debe ser bidimensional.

Comment: solucionaste tu problema? @AlbertOne

Comment: sí amigo muchas gracias. Usé meshgrid después de haber asignado los valores de X y Y @Vichoko.

Answer (score 0):

Así me salió la gráfica:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D    
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
X0=5
Y0=5
A=1
Ox=1
Oy=1
X=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
Y=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
op1=(X-X0)**2
op2=(2*(Ox**2))
op3=(Y-Y0)**2
op4=(2*(Oy**2))
op5=((op1/op2)+(op3/op4))
op6=(op5*-1)
f=np.exp(op6)
Z=A*f
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show() #ipython notebook
#plt.savefig(sys.argv[1])
print("done.")
```

Comment: No solo coloques el código sino explica tu error y como lo solucionaste